# Multiple Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In Project

- Fragment Activity ->  have 2 button Common level
- 3 Fragment -> have Edit Text (each for all)
- view Pager used to show 3 Fragment in Fragment Activity

Goal

I want to take all 3 fragment Edit Text value in Fragment Activity when click on Activity Button

i Used this in Fragment Activity via passing id of edit text but not work help me out

> ((EditText)view.findViewById(id)).getText().toString()

Comment: save the edittext value in variables n try to get it in fragment activity..atleast post what u hv tried already

Comment: http://pastie.org/9377023.html see this

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface in fragment where you keep buttons implement each of them in fragments with edit text and set them in fragment with buttons. On button actions just simply call action from interface.

Described [HERE](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare 3 string fields in your Fragment Activity to store the value of input of each fragment.

FragmentActivity.java:

```
class FragmentActiviy extends... {
    public String textOnFragment1;
    public String textOnFragment2;
    public String textOnFragment3;
    ...
}
```

Fragment1.java:

```
class Fragment1 extends.. {
    FragmentActivity mParent;
    ...
    ...
    input.setTextChangedListener(new OnClickListener() {
        ...
        mParent.textOnFragment1 = input.getText().toString();
    });
}
```

The above is just for demonstrating the idea, not the accurate real code

Comment: got null pointer exception , i used here tab view pager, to show 3 fragment in one fragment activity, its not compulsion to enter value in edit text on each of 3 fragment

Comment: If no value is set to input, you just need to set the textOnFragment(1) to empty

Answer (score 0):

First before going to next `Fragment` just

```
Static String s1=edt1.getText().tostring();
Static String s2=edt1.getText().tostring();
Static String s3=edt1.getText().tostring();
```

Do like this for all there fragment
Then in `MainActivity`

```
case R.id.btn1:  
// fragment 1 edit 
Display(s1);
// fragment 2 edit
Display(s2);
// fragment 3 edit
 Display(s3);
```

break ;

Comment: where are you writing this line s1=edt1.getText().tostring();

Comment: @Override onCreateView

Comment: It s obvious we ll get null.

Comment: where i have to write ??

Comment: Do u have any button in fragment.

Comment: den how you ll get the value.i mean when u ll get.

Comment: Main fragment activity have 2 button save and cancel on bottom and above 3 fragment (Test1,Test2,Test3 are each have edit text) are on tab view pager

Comment: i think u need a button in fragment too.otherwise how u ll get value from edittext

Comment: i want to make button on common level is it possible

Comment: please suggest me not possible